# Java Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am checking to see if an object is null before using it like this

```
if (resturant.getLat() != null)
   //do stuff
```

But it is throwing a `java.lang.NullPointerException` how can I check that restaurant.getLat() is not null?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to write `if (restaurant != null && restaurant.getLat() != null)`

This is because `restaurant` itself might be `null`.

`If` statements in Java are evaluated from left to right `&&` is short-circutted; meaning that once the value of the expression is known, evaluation stops. So the way I've written it is idiomatic.

Comment: *"If statements in Java are evaluated from left to right and are short-circutted"* Not true. You can write `if` that doesn't short-circuit: `if (restaurant != null & restaurant.getLat() != null)`. It's the operators `&&` and `||` that short-circuit, not `if`.

Comment: @m0skit0: Good point, I should be more careful. We'll publish jointly. Have amended.